# Does it make sense to mark up posts about online discounts with "Event"?

Tags: schema.org

I have a news system that creates news posts, and I’m considering whether it makes sense to mark up the results with the [`Event` type from Schema.org](http://schema.org/Event).

The problem is, some of the news posts are about physical events, and some are about online, non-physical, discounts of certain brands/groups of shoes sold on the website.

Does it make sense to mark up an online-only, limited-time (e.g., a week) sale with the `Event` schema?  Has anyone seen that in use and being utilized anywhere?  Or perhaps there’s another different type that would be more appropriate for that?

Comment: By "sale" do you mean a period of time that a store has discounts?  I ask because I think of "online sales" as a synonym for "online commerce".

Comment: I do indeed mean a markdown for a certain period of time that the website has for a subset of items.  The news blurb area here: http://www.shermanbrothers.com/  is the news system that I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it makes sense.  There is even a specific event type for you, the [saleEvent](http://schema.org/SaleEvent).  A sale will use many of the fields of the event schema.

- startDate
- endDate
- duration
- name (like "Macy's Presidents' Day Sale")
- description
- image (website logo maybe?)
- url

You won't be able to put in the location in the case of online-only sales.  Or fields like performers.  Those are not required fields, so it shouldn't be a problem.